# How to block local ip with Windows Firewall?

Tags: network, windows, firewalls

I want to block a local ip-adress in my network but it doesn't work. 
My System is Windows 7 and I have a Webserver running on port 8080.

Let's say I want to block 192.168.178.10. Not just for port 8080 but for all ports on my server.

I did everything in this tutorial: https://www.cm3solutions.com/block-ip-address-ip-range-using-windows-firewall/

On Scope I used the first choice to add a local ip. In this case 192.168.178.10. But I still can access my server from the local ip.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to block access from 192.168.178.10, it should be added to remote IP address instead of the local IP address.